# Continuing CloudKit fetch in background

Tags: ios, background, cloudkit

My goal is to be able to save a record using CloudKit when my app gets backgrounded. I first fetch the record I'm trying to modify, modify it, then save it. I'm making this call from my app delegate's applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
CKDatabase *db = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
CKRecordID *recordId = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"record_a"];

[db fetchRecordWithID:recordId completionHandler:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // Doesn't get here until I foreground the app

    if (!record) // Doesn't exist yet so create it
    {
        record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"SaveData" recordID:recordId];
    }

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path/to/file"];
    CKAsset *saveAsset = [[CKAsset alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL];
    record[@"saveAsset"] = saveAsset;

    [db saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, NSError * _Nullable saveError) {
        // Doesn't get here until I foreground
    }];
}];
```

The completion block for the fetchRecordWithID call doesn't get fired until I foreground the app again, meaning the saveRecord: call doesn't get called until then either.

I've tried using the CKOperation version of fetch and save with modified qualityOfService and queuePriority properties to no avail. Also tried setting the longLived property, but that didn't work either. I've scoured the docs and couldn't find anything that should stop the block from being called when the app is backgrounded.

I have other code that can call through their completion blocks when in the background, so not sure why this would be limited. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm working with the limitation